# Installing dynamic library using cmake

Tags: c++, windows, cmake

I have `C++/Qt` library I wrote myself. I understand that for its distribution, cmake must install .`dll` (or `.so` for Linux) files and header files. So I write the following `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(my_project)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Network Sql REQUIRED)

set(HEADERS some_class.h)
set(SOURCES some_class.cpp)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Core Qt5::Network Qt5::Sql)

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} ARCHIVE DESTINATION "lib"
                                RUNTIME DESTINATION "bin"
                                COMPONENT library)
install(FILES ${HEADERS} DESTINATION "include")
```

And I get the files that want to be in the directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\my_project`:

```
-- lib/libmy_project.dll.a
-- bin/libmy_project.dll
-- include/some_class.h
```

However, once I'm trying to slink my library with a test program:

```
find_package(my_project REQUIRED)
# ....
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} my_project)
```

I have got an error:

```
By not providing "Findmy_project.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
  project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "my_project", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "my_project"
  with any of the following names:

    my_projectConfig.cmake
    my_project-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "my_project" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "my_project_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "my_project" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

That is, he just doesn't understand where to look for him. As I understood, CMake has a configuration file for my project, and CMakeLists.txt for my library should somehow install it. However, information on the internet on this account I found very steep, without explanations and examples (not there sought?). Still, how and where to write these configuration files for libraries?

Comment: There is an "EXPORT" option for Install which can generate such a configuration file for you, see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/command/install.html#installing-exports

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get the final understanding, but I figured out what to write in order to export the library correctly.

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(some_project VERSION 1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

# Parameters initialization
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

# Search for required libraries
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Network Sql REQUIRED)

# Project files
set(HEADERS some_class.h)
set(SOURCES some_class.cpp)

# Building the library
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES})

# Linking the necessary libraries
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Core Qt5::Network Qt5::Sql)

# Setting which header files should be supplied with the library
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER "${HEADERS}")

# Installing the library
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
        EXPORT "${PROJECT_NAME}-config"
        RUNTIME DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}"
        LIBRARY DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}"
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}"
        PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}"
        PRIVATE_HEADER DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}"
        INCLUDES DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}")

install(EXPORT "${PROJECT_NAME}-config" DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME}")

export(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} FILE "${PROJECT_NAME}-exports.cmake")
```